# Ubuntu 22.04 mini freeze and screen glitches

Tags: 22.04, freeze, thinkpad

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed on a Lenovo T16 Thinkpad.

Several times an hour (in the minutes I was typing this, I happened 3 times), when I am moving the cursor, it seems that computer slows down for 2-6 seconds. In those 2-6 seconds, the cursor will not move smoothly. It still goes where I want but in steps, as if frames where being lost. Then screen glitches once or even a few times, showing parts of the screen in different places or artifacts on top of the image at random places in the screen. During the glitching, it's almost impossible to interact with the computer or move the cursor. When the glitching stops (lasts 1-3 seconds) I can use the computer again until the next occurrence.

The computer does not have a discrete GPU.

What can I do?

Comment: Note the exact time of a slowdown. Then check your logs for messages around that time.